# CSS: background image on background color

Tags: css, background, background-image, background-color

I have panel which I colored blue if this panel is being selected (clicked on it). Additionally, I add a small sign (`.png` image) to that panel, which indicates that the selected panel has been already selected before.

So if the user sees for example 10 panels and 4 of them have this small sign, he knows that he has already clicked on those panels before. This work fine so far. The problem is now that I can't display the small sign and make the panel blue at the same time.

I set the panel to blue with the css `background: #6DB3F2;` and the background image with `background-image: url('images/checked.png')`. But it seems that the background color is above the image so you cannot see the sign.

Is it therefore possible to set `z-index`es for the background color and the background image?

Comment: You might want to revisit your choice of accepted answer for this question as the current one is rather misleading.

Answer (score 421, accepted):

You need to use the full property name for each:

```
background-color: #6DB3F2;
background-image: url('images/checked.png');
```

Or, you can use the background shorthand and specify it all in one line:

```
background: url('images/checked.png'), #6DB3F2;
```

Comment: The 1st method did not work for me.  The 2nd, shorthand method works perfectly.

Comment: The reason the first method does not work but the second one does is that the second is **not shorthand for the first**. As per [this significantly better answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47964080/19068) the use of the comma in the `background` property sets **multiple backgrounds** which get layered on top of each other (instead of a single background with an image over a colour).

Answer (score 47):

For me this solution didn't work out:

```
background-color: #6DB3F2;
background-image: url('images/checked.png');
```

But instead it worked the other way:

```
<div class="block">
<span>
...
</span>
</div>
```

the css:

```
.block{
  background-image: url('img.jpg') no-repeat;
  position: relative;
}

.block::before{
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37);
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code Francisc !! As he says, joining the background color and image did not solve the problem for me too. With that help and small changes on my code I managed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 34):

Based on [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Using_multiple_backgrounds) you can set multiple background using shorthand `background` property or individual properties except for `background-color`. In your case, you can do a trick using `linear-gradient` like this:

```
background-image: url('images/checked.png'), linear-gradient(to right, #6DB3F2, #6DB3F2);
```

The first item (image) in the parameter will be put on top. The second item (color background) will be put underneath the first. You can also set other properties individually. For example, to set the image size and position.

```
background-size: 30px 30px;
background-position: bottom right;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Benefit of this method is you can implement it for other cases  easily, for example, you want to make the blue color overlaying the image with certain opacity.

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(109, 179, 242, .6), rgba(109, 179, 242, .6)), url('images/checked.png');
background-size: cover, contain;
background-position: center, right bottom;
background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
```

Individual property parameters are set respectively. Because the image is put underneath the color overlay, its property parameters are also placed after color overlay parameters.

Comment: The third one worked for me. This should be the right answer!

Answer (score 23):

> **And if you want Generate a Black Shadow in the background, you can use
>   the following:**

```
background:linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)100%),url("logo/header-background.png");
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also use short trick to use image and color both like this :-

```
body {
     background:#000 url('images/checked.png');
 }
```

Comment: I tried this, and it also always flashes the background color before showing the image! I used `<div style="background: red url('FILE.jpg')">`. It also flashes red if the red is placed last.

Answer (score 7):

### The next syntax can be used as well.

```
background: <background-color> 
            url('../assets/icons/my-icon.svg')
            <background-position-x background-position-y>
            <background-repeat>;
```

It allows you combining `background-color`, `background-image`, `background-position` and `background-repeat` properties.

### Example

```
background: #696969 url('../assets/icons/my-icon.svg') center center no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 4):

really interesting problem, haven't seen it yet. this code works fine for me. tested it in chrome and IE9

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{
    background-image: url('img.jpg');
    background-color: #6DB3F2;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I styled my colored buttons with an icon in the background

I used "background-color" property for the color and "background" property for the image.

```
  <style>
    .btn {
      display: inline-block;
      line-height: 1em;
      padding: .1em .3em .15em 2em
      border-radius: .2em;
      border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;

      background-color: #cccccc;
    }

    .thumb-up {
      background: url('/icons/thumb-up.png') no-repeat 3px center;
    }

    .thumb-down {
      background: url('/icons/thumb-down.png') no-repeat 3px center;
    }
  </style>

  <span class="btn thumb-up">Thumb up</span>
  <span class="btn thumb-down">Thumb down</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

This actually works for me:

```
background-color: #6DB3F2;
background-image: url('images/checked.png');
```

You can also drop a solid shadow and set the background image:

```
background-image: url('images/checked.png');
box-shadow: inset 0 0 100% #6DB3F2;
```

If the first option is not working for some reason and you don't want to use the box shadow you can always use a pseudo element for the image without any extra HTML:

```
.btn{
    position: relative;
    background-color: #6DB3F2;
}
.btn:before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-image: url('images/checked.png');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for me

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want an icon on the right (or left) then this should work best:

```
.show-hide-button::after {
    content:"";
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    display: inline-block;
    background-size: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    background-position: 0 2px;
    margin-left: .5em;
}
.show-hide-button.shown::after {
    background-image: url(img/eye.svg);
}
```

You could also do `background-size: contain;`, but that should be mostly the same. the `background-position` will depened on your image.

Then you can easily do an alternative state on hover:

```
.show-hide-button.shown:hover::after {
    background-image: url(img/eye-no.svg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with **box shadow: inset**

```
.second_info_block {
  background: url('imageURL');
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`<li style="background-color: #ffffff;"><a href="/<%=logo_marka_url%>"><img border="0" style="border-radius:5px;background: url(images/picture.jpg') 50% 50% no-repeat;width:150px;height:80px;" src="images/clearpixel.gif"/></a></li>`

Other Sample Box Center Image and  Background Color

1.First clearpixel fix image area
2.style center image area box
3.li background or div color style

Comment: Inline CSS is not appropriate if there is any other reasonable option.

Answer (score -11):

```
body 
{
background-image:url('image/img2.jpg');
margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}
```