# Multiple background-color layers

Tags: css, background-image, background-color

I wondered if it was possible to create two background-colors for a div an overlay them.

I want a white background-color so that the content below this div doesn't shine through and another rgba() color painted over this white to create lighter colors per script.

Comment: Why not immediately select the correct color? And as far as I know you can onl stack background images, not colours.

Comment: Because I need to generate a lot of different light colors from my initial color...

Comment: You'll need to create/insert the different semi-transparent colours anyway... It's equal the work.

Comment: No it is not! Trust me :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Without understanding why you want this, it can be done by using solid color gradients: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pymg6g6c/).

```
body {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(220,14,120,0.5), rgba(220,14,120,0.5)),
                linear-gradient(white, white); /* first bg is on top of this */

}
```

Comment: @BramVanroy: Thanks -- this is also nice because all of the other background properties apply.

Comment: I still don't understand why the OP needs this though, why not immediately select the correct HEX color?

Comment: Because selecting an single rgba color would allow the background of the parent so show through. The OP wants a single background color to eliminate the opacity then have an rgba color on top of that clean 'canvas'.

Comment: The bottom layer could simply be a background-color. You only need to use the gradient trick for additional layers.

Comment: > Specifying multiple backgrounds is easy:
> `.myclass { background: background1, background2, /* … ,*/ backgroundN; }`
> [Using multiple backgrounds - Mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Using_multiple_backgrounds)

Comment: @Nor.Z You can do background: background1, background2... with both the shorthand background property and the individual properties thereof except for background-color

Answer (score 3):

Though [Adrift's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28592238/1150683) is the way to go, you can also use pseudo elements for this.

```
body {
    background: white;
    position: relative;
}

body:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left; 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(220,14,120,0.5);
    z-index: 1;
}

/* Just to be sure, automatically set all elements to a higher z-index than the pseudo element */
body * {
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pymg6g6c/1/).

However, this is not production friendly:

- Setting position relative on body and all other elements when not necessary
- Setting unnecessary z-index on all elements

The only upside this method has, is that it doesn't use gradients which, from a semantic standpoint, is more logical.

Answer (score 1):

You can't define two background-colors for one element, but you could overlay one coloured element on top of a white one in order to get a blending effect, while blocking out anything below them:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b2nbpyn6/1/)

HTML

```
<div class="one">
    <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.one {
    background-color: #fff;
}
.two {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve **multiple background colors** in CSS, a common proposal is

- Solid Color Gradients

But there is an alternative:

- Solid Color `background-images` via **SVG Data URIs**

---

The working example below contains the following areas with the following background colors:

- `<main>` - *dark-gray*
- `<section>` - *light-gray*
- `<div class="circle">` - *translucent red*

In this set-up, we want to use the same theme-color for all the circles, `rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)` but we also want the circles inside the `<section>` to appear to have the same `background-color` as the circle outside `<section>`.

We can observe that, due to the application of the technique below to `div.circle.does-not-blend` - the *rightmost* of the two circles inside `<section>` - that circle ends up with the same apparent `background-color` as `div.circle` *outside* `<section>`.

---

### The Approach

The approach is to give `div.circle.does-not-blend`:

- the same initial `background-color` as `<main>`
- an **SVG Data URI** `background-image` with the same *translucent red* `background-color` as the other `.circle` elements

---

### The SVG `background-image`

The **SVG Data URI** `background-image` looks like this:

```
data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="background-color:rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);"%2F%3E
```

---

### The Result

In the final result we see that the light-gray `background-color` of `<section>` does not bleed through and influence the final `background-color` of `div.circle.does-not-blend`

---

**Working Example**

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  height: 180px;
  padding: 0 9px;
  background-color: rgb(127, 127, 127);
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 0 0 66%;
  background-color: rgb(191, 191, 191);
  height: 162px;
}

.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 120px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.circle.does-not-blend {
  background-color: rgb(127, 127, 127);
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="background-color:rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);"%2F%3E');
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <section>
    <div class="circle">Incorrect</div>
    <div class="circle does-not-blend">Correct</div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, yes there is a way. You can use a background image and a background color on the same div. [Check out this SOF post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195215/css-background-image-on-background-color)

Although I would consider a different method like this:

Structure:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="color"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
    position: relative:
}
.white, .color {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
.white {
    z-index: 9998;
}
.color {
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

You can mess around with the [details here](http://jsfiddle.net/e7qyn523/), but the overall idea is that your layer the divs on top of each other. The div with the higher z-index will be on top. Change their colors accordingly. The parent div being relative will keep the absolute divs inside of that container.