# Hiding Secondary scrollbar with css and [ngStyle] question

Tags: css, angular, sass, ng-style

So I've this page where the content adds dynamically, but some of the content needs scrolling, I don't want to have two scrols, it's ugly.

I've tried some stuff but nothing seem to work

css looking right now :

```
element {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none; 
  overflow-y: scroll; 
}

element::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none; 
}
```

[image: Double scroll bar]

Also I wanted to check if there's some incompatibility with this code

```
<section id="banner" [ngStyle]="{ 'background': 'url(' + this.imgCenario + ') center/100% no-repeat', 'background-color': 'rgb(234,239,239)'}"
    [ngClass]="classBanner" class="imageContainer">
```

The background color apllies but when the image loads it goes away, I can input it through the console, but I think that i'm missing something here. Is there a way to do this or it will always make the picture the main setting, even if the picture doesn't cover the whole area

Answer (score 1):

Theres a simmilar question about the background-color and the background-image properties.

[CSS: background image on background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195215/css-background-image-on-background-color)

It seems like you are overrigind your background-image when you use background-color. As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195215/css-background-image-on-background-color) you can provide the color and the image using just the background property, something like `[ngStyle]="{ 'background': 'url(' + this.imgCenario + ') center/100% no-repeat rgb(234,239,239)'}"`

Comment: Ty, i've tryed to do it like this but for some reason i was gettin errors, probablly the sintax

Answer (score 0):

For the scroll I've found the problem, i was calling it wrong

```
 *::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

* {
  font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  -ms-overflow-style: none; 
  scrollbar-width: none; 
  overflow-y: scroll; 
}
```